# VueJS - Detecting DOM changes inside the scope of VueJS when using sortableJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

I am trying to use sortableJS with vueJS. Everything is working fine but VueJS is not able to detect the changes that are done in the scope of sortableJS since sortable JS changes the DOM directly.

I have passed 'this' from vue's instance to onEnd method of sortable. An event is triggered when I drag/drop an element on screen. I get the newIndex as well as oldIndex. When I swap the two indexes, the changes made to the DOM are now detected somehow and the array elements are swapped twice.

I want a way by which I can tell Vue to detect a change made in the DOM. Or a solution that works.

```
onEnd: function(evt) {        
        self.showIcons = true;
        document.body.style.cursor = "unset";

        // changing order of items
        const oldIndex = evt.oldIndex;
        const newIndex = evt.newIndex;

        const tempTodos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self.todos));
        const tempItem = tempTodos.slice(oldIndex, oldIndex+1);
        tempTodos.splice(oldIndex, 1);
        tempTodos.splice(newIndex, 0, ...tempItem);
        self.todos = tempTodos;
```

Actual result - 
   Original array - [1, 2, 3]
   If I drag 3 and swap with 1 then new array gets swapped twice (once 
   by onEnd and once by DOM detection). So the new array is - [2, 3, 1]

Expected result - 
   Original array - [1, 2, 3]
   If I drag 3 and swap with 1 then the new array should be - [3, 2, 1]

Comment: Try using an arrow function (`onEnd: () => { ... }`) so you can use `this` directly.

Comment: Just use https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Comment: @Frank did not work. The fat arrow function found `this` but the array didn't update after the swap operation.